# HighStock chart.rangeSelector after loading

Tags: highcharts

I know how to set the default range selector when defining a new chart by using

```
rangeSelector: {
    selected:0,
},
```

Is it possible to change this after new data has been loaded though javascript?

eg:

```
chart.series[0].setData(new data);
somethinghere rangeselector selected = 2;
```

I can set it using the range extreme, but this doesn't highlight the button to show the user what date range is selected and it would ( I think) make for a cleaner way of setting the date.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible by catching button event and add state.

http://jsfiddle.net/jGALb/

```
 chart.rangeSelector.buttons[4].setState(2);
 chart.rangeSelector.clickButton(4,4,true);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had some issues with this answer. Looking at the source for the latest stable version of Highstock,  here's the argument documentation for the clickButton signature,

```
@param {Number} i The index of the button
@param {Object} rangeOptions
@param {Boolean} redraw
```

My example here is for a custom button to display the last 12 hours.

```
var rangeOptions = {
    type: "hour",
    count: 12
};

chart.rangeSelector.clickButton(2,rangeOptions,true);
```

Notice, I didn't need to set the button state either.